# Show three images from each user

Tags: php, mysql, loops, picturegallery

I have a pictures table where users pictures are saving with their ID and pic physical link.

```
userID  |  picture
1       |  picnameLink
1       |  picnameLink
2       |  picnameLink
1       |  picnameLink
2       |  picnameLink
3       |  picnameLink
```

Now, I want to show maximum 3 pictures in a jquery picture gallery block where one block should show all 3 pictures from one same user and if a user have less than 3 pictures, it should show no image text.

I have tried to do with group by mysql query but I am not getting desired result. Do I have to use two loops?

--Edit for fthiella-- Here is code

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pictures GROUP BY userID";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $image_array[] = $row['picLink'];
    $id_array[] = $row['pic_id'];
}
$num_images_to_display = 3; /* MODIFY TO REFLECT NUMBER OF IMAGES TO SHOW PER SCREEN */
$num_images = count($image_array);
$image_path = "../images/"; /* MODIFY TO REFLECT THE PATH TO YOUR IMAGES */
$y = $num_images_to_display;
if(!isset($_GET['first'])){
        $first = 0;
    }else{
        $first = (int) $_GET['first'];
}
$x = $num_images - 1;
$z = $x - $y;
if($first>$z) {
    $first = $z;
}
$last = $first + $num_images_to_display;
```

And here is HTML area:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:100px; width:800px; text-align: center;">
    <?PHP
    $i = $first;
    while($i<$last) { $showme = $image_path . $image_array[$i]; ?>

<?php if($image_array[$i]!="") { ?><img src="<?PHP echo $showme; ?>" width="176px" height="197px"><?php } else { ?><img src="../image/no_image.jpg" width="176px" height="197px"><?PHP } ?>

    $prev = $first-1;
    $next = $first +1;
    if($prev<0){ $prev = 0; }
    ?>
</div>
```

Result of this query shows pictures in groups but I want maximum three pictures of each user where no image shows if a user has less than three images.

Comment: Show the code that you have tried.  Then tell us what it *is* doing and how it is different from what you *want* it to do.

Comment: I don't see any code, but what you should do is edit the original posting and paste it in there.

Comment: Sorry Andy, I just edited my main question with code as I am new here.

Comment: I don't have any answers, but I was just the first to say "Show us the code".

Comment: @travis i'm trying to understand what you are looking for.. what is `first` ? do you need to show exactly three images inside <div></div>?

Comment: Yes, three images inside div

Comment: @travis starting from `first`? but is first something like the page number? so if first=0, show image1,image2,image3 (or empty images) of first user, first=1 show image1,image2,image3 of second user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if there's a better solution, but i think you could use this:

```
SELECT p1.userID, p1.picture as pic1, p2.picture as pic2, p3.picture as pic3
FROM
  pictures p1 left join pictures p2
  on p1.userID=p2.userID and p1.picture<>p2.picture
  left join pictures p3
  on p1.userID=p3.userID and p1.picture<>p3.picture and p2.picture<>p3.picture
GROUP BY p1.userID
```

This will select three images for each user. If a user has less than three images, it will show nulls, if it has more, it chooses three between all of them.

An alternative, that show three images each one in a different row, is this query that makes use of variables:

```
SELECT userid, picture
FROM (
  SELECT
    userid,
    picture,
    case when @prec_id=userid then @row:=@row+1 else @row:=1 end as row,
    @prec_id:=userid
  FROM 
    `pictures`,
    (SELECT @prec_id:=0, @row:=0) s
  ORDER BY userid) s
WHERE row<=3
```

**EDIT:** to show three images for each user at a time I would use my first query, and I would start with some code like this:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "test");

$image_path = "../images/";
$no_image = "../image/no_image.jpg";

if(!isset($_GET['first'])){
  $first = 0;
} else {
  $first = (int) $_GET['first'];
}

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT p1.userID, p1.picture as pic1, p2.picture as pic2, p3.picture as pic3
FROM
  pictures p1 left join pictures p2
  on p1.userID=p2.userID and p1.picture<>p2.picture
  left join pictures p3
  on p1.userID=p3.userID and p1.picture<>p3.picture and p2.picture<>p3.picture
GROUP BY p1.userID
LIMIT ?,1")) {

    $stmt->bind_param("i", $first); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($user, $pic1, $pic2, $pic3);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
<div style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:100px; width:800px; text-align: center;">
  <img src="<?PHP echo (isset($pic1) ? $image_path.$pic1 : $no_image); ?>" width="176px" height="197px">
  <img src="<?PHP echo (isset($pic2) ? $image_path.$pic2 : $no_image); ?>" width="176px" height="197px">
  <img src="<?PHP echo (isset($pic3) ? $image_path.$pic3 : $no_image); ?>" width="176px" height="197px">
</div>
```

(it has be improved, but you could start with it. I'm using mysqli instead of mysql)

Comment: Does this always pick .picture values from a single row?  I'd be worried that p1.picture might choose a different grouped row than p3.picture (causing them to be the same).

Comment: nice, but say it was 100, is there an alternative to the alised joins?

Comment: @dagon i edited and added an alternative, it uses variables so it is not standard SQL but works only in MySql

Comment: @ebyrob sorry, i don't understand... p1.userid, p2.userid and p3.userid are always the same, and pictures are always different so they are always on different rows... i think it should be ok

Comment: +1 for that pretty nice solution ... i was just fiddeling the same :o)

Comment: @SirRufo thanks :) i usually prefer not to use variables and to use just standard sql, but sometimes they make things easier :)

Comment: SubSelects with Limit are also possible but can be very slow, so this is a really good answer

Comment: sweet, hope i can remember that when i need it :-)

Comment: @fthiella, thanks for this great code. But could you please check my original question where I have pasted my code and suggest how can I use your code in mine as I am using jquery too for a proper picture gallery.

Comment: @fthiella, sorry if its annoying but I am asking because till now I have only used simple queries and that's why I am finding difficult to apply your's complicated one.

Comment: @fthiella, you are awesome, brilliant. Solved problem in minutes with which I was fighting for a week. Now, only one question. If I have to apply a check like "Fetch records where publicshowing=1" where I should write the check in your query?