# mysqli fetch records

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqlimport, picturegallery

This is regarding a post [Show three images from each user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980078/show-three-images-from-each-user) where there is a great solution for a same issues which I was having.

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT p1.userID, p1.picture as pic1, p2.picture as pic2, p3.picture as pic3
FROM
  pictures p1 left join pictures p2
  on p1.userID=p2.userID and p1.picture<>p2.picture
  left join pictures p3
  on p1.userID=p3.userID and p1.picture<>p3.picture and p2.picture<>p3.picture
GROUP BY p1.userID
LIMIT ?,1")) {

    $stmt->bind_param("i", $first); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($user, $pic1, $pic2, $pic3);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
<div style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:100px; width:800px; text-align: center;">
  <img src="<?PHP echo (isset($pic1) ? $image_path.$pic1 : $no_image); ?>" width="176px" height="197px">
  <img src="<?PHP echo (isset($pic2) ? $image_path.$pic2 : $no_image); ?>" width="176px" height="197px">
  <img src="<?PHP echo (isset($pic3) ? $image_path.$pic3 : $no_image); ?>" width="176px" height="197px">
</div>
```

I was wondering how can I also get pictureID as well in this query? E.g if I use pictures for voting, I would then have to get pictureID as well.

**Answer after Supericy help:**(if someone looking for same)

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT p1.userID, p1.picture as pic1, p1.pictureID as pic1id, p2.picture as pic2, p2.pictureID as pic2id, p3.picture as pic3, p3.pictureID as pic3id
FROM
  pictures p1 left join pictures p2
  on p1.userID=p2.userID and p1.picture<>p2.picture
  left join pictures p3
  on p1.userID=p3.userID and p1.picture<>p3.picture and p2.picture<>p3.picture
GROUP BY p1.userID
LIMIT ?,1")) {
```

And then bind it

```
$stmt->bind_result($user, $pic1, $pic1id, $pic2, $pic2id, $pic3, $pic3id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the picture's ID column is named "pictureID":

```
SELECT p1.userID, p1.picture as pic1, p1.pictureID as pic1id, p2.picture as pic2, p2.pictureID as pic2id, p3.picture as pic3, p3.pictureID as pic3id
FROM
  pictures p1 left join pictures p2
  on p1.userID=p2.userID and p1.picture<>p2.picture
  left join pictures p3
  on p1.userID=p3.userID and p1.picture<>p3.picture and p2.picture<>p3.picture
GROUP BY p1.userID
LIMIT ?,1
```

and then when binding the result:

```
$stmt->bind_result($user, $pic1, $pic1id, $pic2, $pic2id, $pic3, $pic3id);
```

Comment: Sounds good, but do I then have to bind its variable as well in bind_result ?

Comment: Oh right, yes. `$stmt->bind_result($user, $pic1, $pic1_id, $pic2, $pic2_id, $pic3, $pic3_id);` (edited my answer)

Comment: I tried but it gives "Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result() [mysqli-stmt.bind-result]: Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement"

Comment: I just have one more question please, what if i want to add a check like "selecting only images where approved=1", where would I write it in query?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT p1.userID,coalesce(p1.pictureID,p2.pictureID,p3.pictureID) pictureID, 
       coalesce(p1.picture,p2.picture,p3.picture) as pic
FROM
  pictures p1 left join pictures p2
  on p1.userID=p2.userID and p1.picture<>p2.picture
  left join pictures p3
  on p1.userID=p3.userID and p1.picture<>p3.picture and p2.picture<>p3.picture
GROUP BY p1.userID,pictureID,pic
LIMIT ?,1
```